# How to use a random number in a WHERE range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to select all datasets within a range from 0 to a generated random number.

This works:

```
@test = Test.where( :level => 0..4 )
```

This doesn't work:

```
@test = Test.where( :level => 0..rand(4) )
```

If I put **rand(4)** as the upper limit of the range I don't get any result. Why? How can I do it?

Thanks

Edit: Sorry, I was not aware that rand(4) means that 4 is not in the range and that 3 is the maximum result. I solved this now. Thank you.

Comment: Try with this `@test = Test.where( :level => rand(0..4) )`

Comment: what you said does not work works fine, I just tested from a rails console, can you please post what error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this ..

```
a=Random.new

@test = Test.where(:level=>0..(x*a.rand))   # where x is the no of level .
```

or do this ..

```
@test= Test.where (:level=>0..a.integer(x))  # where x is same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any results when `rand(4)` returns `0`.

Try using [`Array#sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) to generate a random number between 1 and 4:

```
@test = Test.where( :level => 0..(1..4).to_a.sample )
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Ruby 1.9.3 or greater you can you can use Kernel#rand (wich accepts ranges)

example:

```
@test = Test.where(id: 0..rand(0..4))
```

edit: as bjhaid pointed out, it was not doing a between query

Comment: this would not do a `between` query

Comment: You are absolutly right. I've tried and this works    Test.where(id: 0..rand(0..4))